# Given a sorted array, output all triplets <a,b,c> such that a-b = c

Tags: c, algorithm

Given a sorted array, output all triplets  such that a-b = c.
The code I tried so far is as below; but there are following test cases-

```
-12 = -7 - 5
-12 =  3 - 15
 -7 = -4 - 3
 -7 =  3 - 10
 -7 =  9 - 16
 -4 =  5 - 9
  3 = -4 - -7
  5 = -7 - -12
  5 = 15 - 10 
 10 = 3 - -7 
 10 = 15 - 5
15 = 3 - (-12)
16 = 9 - (-7)
```

while my program prints only-

```
-12 = -7 - 5
 -7 = -4 - 3
 -12 = 3 - 15
 -7 = 3 - 10
 -4 = 5 - 9
 -7 = 9 - 16
 5 = 15 - 10
```

means only the abs difference! Any suggestion ll be great help!

```
void binder(int*a, int n) {
    int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int current = a[i];
    int left = 0;
    int right = n-1;
    while (left < right) {
      if ( left == i ) {
        left++;
        continue;
      }


if (right == i) {
        right--;
        continue;
      }



if (a[left] + a[right] < current) {
        left++;
      } else if (a[left] + a[right] > current) {
        right--;
      } else {
        printf("\n %d = %d - %d",a[left],current, a[right]);
        left++;
        right--;
      }
    }
  }
}



int main() {
  int a[] = {-12, -7, -4, 0, 3, 5, 9, 10, 15, 16};
  binder(a, 10);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `a-b=c` is the same as `a=b+c` which may help visualize solutions. (Or may not).

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though the test case is also missing a triplet:

```
9 =  5 - (-4)
```

Try changing your printing from:

```
printf("\n %d = %d - %d",a[left],current, a[right]);
```

to:

```
printf("\n %d = %d - %d",a[left],current, a[right]);
printf("\n %d = %d - %d",a[right],current, a[left]);
```

Comment: That's right! If `c=b-a` then `a=b-c` and both (a,b,c) and (c,b,a) are valid pairs. That's the only thing missing in the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is O(n^3), but it should work.

```
void binder(int*a, int n)
{
    for(int left = 0; left < n; left++)
    {
        for(int right = 0; right < n; right++)
        {
            for(int result = 0; result < n; result++)
            {
                if(left != right && left != result && result != right && a[left] - a[right] == a[result])
                    printf("\n %d = %d - %d", a[result], a[left], a[right]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that the array is sorted you can pick two numbers and then search for the third one using binary search. In this case you will get O(n^2*lgn) complexity.

Comment: @daniel b Yeah, I had thought of that but couldn't be bothered with it.

Comment: @Daniel B, Or one could just, for each possible difference, do a simultaneous double traversal of the list in order to find elements separated by that much. That is O(n²), with no log factor. (We cannot do asymptotically better than that, because the input [0,1,...,n] will produce about n²/2 different triples to output).

Comment: Would you give the obvious O(n^3) answer in an interview? The arguments of programming complexity vs computational complexity tradeoff could be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If they are sorted, (and as Hanning pointed out, a-b=c is the same as a=b+c) you can start with the smallest b and c, and add them, and this should lead to the smallest a. Now while increasing b or c, a can only get bigger too, so you should have never to look back.

If you make a table of b's and c's and their sum (which should be one of the a's):

```
c\ b:-12    3   4   5   7  10  15 16  
-12: -24, -19, -9, -7, -3, -2,  3, 4
 -7:  -9,  -4,  6,  8, 12, 13, 18, 
  3:  -8,  -3,  7,  9, 13, 14, 19, 
  5:  -7,  -2,  8, 10, 14, 15, 
  9:  -5,   0, 10, 12, 16, 
 10:  -2,   3, 13, 15,  
 15:   3,   8, 18,  
 16:   4,   9, 19,
```

you see, that I omited the values on the lower right, because the previous value (from left) already exceeded the maximum a (15), so a higher value can't match.

Of course, for such a small number of equations, you waste much more time thinking about optimization, than you gain from omitting superfluous calculations. For much bigger sets of values, it might be useful, to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
HashTable table;
for b = 0 to n-1:
    for c = 0 to n-1:
        table[b + c] = <b, c>
    end for
end for

for a = 0 to n-1:
    if table[a] exists and (<b, c> in table[a] where b != a and c != a) then:
        output <a, b, c>
    end if
end for
```

So, if we consider "a=b+c", for each (b, c) pair of values, we place that in a hash table, associating it with the (b, c) pair [O(n^2)].

Then, we go through the array again and if a value appears in the hash table, and the associated pairs are for different indices, then we've found a new entry (rearranging the terms back into "a-b=c"). This step is O(n), resulting in a O(n^2) solution overall.

I think we can see this question as a variation on the "find pairs of values in an array that sum up to S, for a fixed S" problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed one more iteration/loop in your code. since you are using brute force strategy so analysis say that it will take O(n^3) space and you code's time complexity seems O(n^2).
here is the case which will help you to understand.
you check for :
`a = b-c`
and you skip the check for :
`c = b-a`